How to manage Daily Reset Time
I want to implement a daily reward system in my game but am unsure how to manage the reset time effectively. Initially, I considered using the phone's local date and time. However, this approach has a significant drawback: if users change their device's date and time, they could potentially claim rewards multiple times in a day, which would be problematic.
Another idea I had was to base the reset time on the user's country by determining their time zone from their IP address and using the time zone of the capital city. While this method works well for countries with a single time zone, like France, it could be frustrating for users in countries with multiple time zones, such as the USA. Users might receive their rewards at inconvenient times, like 2 AM or 4 AM local time.
I've read about using NTP (Network Time Protocol) servers to synchronize time, but I have no experience with setting them up. Could using NTP servers be complex or costly for an independent developer like me?
I would appreciate any insights or experiences you might have on this topic. Are there any resources or best practices you can recommend?

This can only properly work if you save the reward state on a server, assuming you have one in your setup.
In that case you can set a flag on the server-side if for any given day the reward was claimed. You can then let the user decide (automatically based on the locale or even allow them to configure this themselves) at what local time the reset should occur. Since you save the state on the server, there is no way the reward can be earned repeatedly for the same day, but you still have the flexibility to use customized times for each user.

Thank you for you answer, can you tell me about "automatically based on locale", how to retrieve locale reliably? I guess I need to make a system check for locale settings?

You can use Locale.getDefault().
